# Transition to view controller in Menu Bar

Tags: ios, swift, menu, menuitem, menubar

I finished following this Tutorial on a Menu Side Bar by Gary Tokman (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKh1b3ctCf4  3 PART SERIES), where he creates a menu bar that opens a view that changes color based on the item in the menu bar he presses on. 
 However since I actually want to make it open view controllers, I was looking in the comments to see if someone had the same idea, which they did in the top comment. 
 However what the user is doing, is everytime a menu item is selected, it just places a subview on top of the current view. 
 After using the menu bar a couple of times, you can see that the views are just stacking on each other and memory is building up. 
 Is there a viable way to remove each view when a new menu item is selected or some other method. 
 Also another side question of this would be: when the menu bar is opened is there a way to touch the black part of the screen and close it without selecting a menu item. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are basically trying to implement a [container view controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html).

Comment: there are already solutions given in that comment, have you used those or something else , please describe

Comment: Can you post some of the actual code?

Answer (score 1):

For changing view controller implementation of container view controller seems to be the best solution. As for your questions:

**Is there a viable way to remove each view when a new menu item is selected or some other method.**

Yes, it looks like that (for example in HomeViewController):
before adding new view call this method

```
func clearSubviews() {
            for v in self.view.subviews {
                    v.removeFromSuperview()
                }
        }
```

For **when the menu bar is opened is there a way to touch the black part of the screen and close it without selecting a menu item.**

just create a method for transitioning back - basically like `animateTransition(...)` but without changing anything except frames. Then create gesture recognizer and add it to dimmingView like that:

```
var recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(transitionBack))
        dimmingView.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
```

gesture recognizer shouldn't get called when dimmingView alpha is set to zero so it won't be called when menu is hidden.

of course `transitionBack` must have `@objc` adnotation to make it possible to be action in this recognizer.

Good luck!